# SQL Server 2008 displays data it should not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, aspdotnetstorefront

I have a really strange problem with SQL Server 2008. We have an e-commerce cart ASPDOTNETSTOREFRONT and we set the product category to UNPUBLISHED(via the carts admin section), and in the database record is set as 0 which is correct.

We refresh the page and the category is gone from the webpage.

All day yesterday the category *wasnt* showing and then today the category is now showing in the page and in the admin section and database its set to un-published. It makes no logical sense whats so ever!

The server has a C:\ is 25GB and only has 100MB free space! and the OS is loaded onto it with SQL Server but the websites are hosted on the D:\ which has 500GB of free space.

What can i do to investigate this further? (Please migrate this if its in the wrong stack website but i think programmers would maybe experiance something similar so might have a solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because the XML package `entity.grid.xml.config` didnt contain the following:

```
<xsl:choose>                      
<xsl:when test="Published=1">
<xsl:call-template name="SubCatCell">
<xsl:with-param name="scName" select="$scName" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:when>
```

The sub category is now checking if its published, if it IS, then show it.

Answer (score 1):

The categories of the products disappeared most likely because you set those products as unpublished.  In regards to the website not viewing the updates in `real-time`, this is the weird stuff with ASP.Net, sometimes saving the `web.config` file without making any changes to it, updates the website cache and views the changes.. I know, it's weird.  Otherwise, you may need to press `reset cache` button in the storefront admin.

Comment: Done that so many times. Its really strange behavior. Is there something in IIS that i should set up or change? I have it as classic mode in .NET 2. I have the main application then inside it are the country websites set up as applications.

Comment: Done what?  save the web.config without changes?

Comment: Also, is there a reason it's not in integrated mode?

Comment: I have changed the app pool so its in integrated mode, i have 'touched' the web.config file and saved it, cleared my browser cache and the category still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SQL Profiler to check what sql queries are run by the ASP.Net application. If sql server is actually returning data that it should not, then investigate data in the tables. If SQL server is not returning the data, but it is displayed, then the problem is with cache somewhere: either with storefront or with your browser.

Comment: Cant be the browser, as we've tested this on multiple machines. Thanks i am just about to use the Profiler.

Comment: @Super1 To be honest, I only slightly expected browser to be that bad. Either data is corrupt, or storefront is on crack!

Comment: or the server with only 100MB free space is causing an issue. Thats like less than 1%!!

Comment: yeah 100MB is definitely not good. Glad you found the solution. Would you mind posting it as your answer with detailed explanation. For future reference.

Comment: I didnt find the solution! but i am taking the code and database to a server that has space and we'll see if it still displays!

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably happens due to the caching feature in IIS, server or browser if it is a web-app. You basically, need to make your checks in severeal places:

- By querying the database, where new record creation may still
  reference values from front-end application
- Caching in client and server sides
- Use SQL profiler and Fiddler for web-application